# map ls -a to ls -A

Tags: bash, ls, alias, dot-files

I have tried to made an `alias ls -a = ls -A`, ending up with:

```
bash: alias: `ls -a': invalid alias name
```

I want `ls -a` without `.` and `..`. How can I get that?

Comment: Is there something stopping your from just using `ls -A`?  Sorry, but I'm not sure I understand. You want to type `ls -a`, but you want it to execute `ls -A`? Since an alias needs to be a single word, what abut using `lA` instead?

Comment: my muscle memory...i giess! it always forget that `shift`, and i get `ls -a`! :)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use alias like that. Aliases are single names and are invoked without any arguments (all arguments are passed to aliased commands directly without modification).

My proposition to solve the problem you are facing is to use a function and only then alias it to `ls`, like that:

```
_ls() {
      if [[ "$1" == "-a" ]]; then
          shift
          ls -A "$@"
      else
          ls "$@"
      fi
}
alias ls=_ls
```

Notice that this way only `ls -a` will be affected (`-a` needs to be alone on the first position), so you can still access "standard" `-a` by putting it on other places or gather it with other options:

```
ls -a              # modified '-a'
ls -a -l /tmp      # modified '-a'
ls -al             # not modified
ls -l -a /tmp      # not modified
```

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that OP's alias syntax has some errors as well.

Comment: What's the reason for using both an alias and a function here?

Comment: @Kusalananda My bash version (4.4.23) doesn't allow to create function in the form `fun() {  }` with the same name as previously defined alias (and for `ls` that's often the case by default for many distributions). I can do that with `function fun` form, but then `$1` doesn't return argument of function, but rather argument of previously defined alias. By creating a function and then "re-alias" this we fix the problem in somewhat convoluted way.

Comment: @jimmij `unalias ls`?

Comment: @Kusalananda but then you lose all previously defined switches like `--color` etc.

Comment: @jimmij Would you not loose them as soon as you redefine the alias?

Comment: @Kusalananda that would require first check what the command is aliased to.

Comment: @jimmij I'm confused, but I'll let this go.